# Temporary way to mitigate Meltdown before official fix?

Tags: kernel, security, javascript, vulnerability

As I understand it this vulnerability is about browser behavior, would turning off javascript be a temporary mitigation
against attack?

Comment: The attack concerns any (potentially) untrusted code that runs on your machine - so yes, that could include JavaScript (but not _just_ JavaScript or brrowsers). So yes, turning off JavaScript would mitigate issues coming from malicious JavaScript. However, fixes for major browsers [are already out or will be soon](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/mozilla-confirms-web-based-execution-vector-for-meltdown-and-spectre-attacks/).

Comment: @JonasCz That would be for Spectre, not Meltdown. Meltdown is about page table manipulation and accessing kernel memory, which you can't do from JS in the browser. But yes, "don't run software" is the best way to mitigate attacks from software. :)